# EditTextPreferences Validation

Tags: android, validation, sharedpreferences, edittextpreference

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code. For some reason the OnSharedPreferencesChanged is not being called when changing the value. I am trying to check if the PIN entered is equal to 2 digits or no. But for it just doesnt work..
can anyone help me out.

Thanks.!

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    EditTextPreference editPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        this.editPreference = ((EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen()
                .findPreference("userPass"));
        Log.d("TAG","before sharedPreferenceChanged");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        Log.d("TAG","In SharedPreferences");
        if (sharedPreferences.getString("userPass", null).length() != 2) {
            Log.d("TAG","lenght is less than 1");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Pin has to be 2 digits only",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.editPreference.setText(null);
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pin set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [setOnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29) for your editPreference in onCreate(), put your validation code inside this callback.

Reading the docs, they say [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) is called when the shared preference is changed(is already changed). In the other hand the setOnPreferenceChangeListener is triggered "when this Preference is changed by the user (but before the internal state has been updated)"